# How to select specific records in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I only want to deal with measurement values have "Cookies made" and "Hours". I am just wondering how I would either create a subset of those values? I have tried using group_by function, n_distinct, and the arrange function.

Data:

```
working day working week    franchise_id    measurement     amount
# Create subset data based off of Cookies made and Hours only
01-01-2020  01-01-2020      1               Cookies made    100 
01-01-2020  01-01-2020      1               Hours           1
# Create subset data based off of Cookies made, Bread made, Hours only
01-02-2020  01-01-2020      2               Cookies made    100
01-02-2020  01-01-2020      2               Bread made      50  
01-02-2020  01-01-2020      2               Hours           3
# Create subset data based off of Hours only
01-03-2020  01-01-2020     31               Hours           10
# Create subset data based off of Cookies made, and Bread made only
01-03-2020  01-01-2020     32               Cookies made    10
01-03-2020  01-01-2020     32               Bread made      10
# Create subset data that has Cookies, Bread made and hours corresponding to it.
01-04-2020  01-01-2020     4                Cookies made    10
01-04-2020  01-01-2020     4                Bread made      10
01-04-2020  01-01-2020     4                Hours           2 #Note that this hour represents cookies made
01-04-2020  01-01-2020     4                Hours           5 # This hour is for the bread
#etc.
01-05-2020  01-05-2020    5                 Bread made      100 
01-05-2020  01-05-2020    5                 Hours           1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` to subset data rows by condition.

```
filter(your_data, measurement %in% c("Cookies made", "Hours"))
```

> I have tried using group_by function, n_distinct, and the arrange function.

`arrange` is for sorting rows, `n_distinct` will tell you the number of distinct values, and `group_by` prepares data for grouped operations that will follow. I'd suggest looking at the excellent [Intro to dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) vignette to get acquainted with the basic `dplyr` functions.

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, how would I get something like where I am given the "cookies made, bread made, hours, hours" vs. "cookies made, bread made, hours". I realized that using the filter command above would not work in this case.

Comment: I think I understand.  Your spreadsheet has a problem in that there are rows that SAY the same thing but MEAN different things.  You will need to separate those with some logic statements.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but it sounds like you want to do pattern matching rather than exact matching. For that you could use the `stringr` package function `str_detect`. So `filter(your_data, str_detect(measurement, "Cookies|Hours"))` will give you all rows where the `measurement` column contains the word "Cookies" or contains the word "Hours".